# capital gains on foreign investment

Tags: united-states, taxes, capital-gains-tax, dtaa

I recently sold a property in Panama. A capital gains tax was imposed by Panama at time of sale. As a U.S. citizen will I need to pay another capital gains tax?

Comment: The US taxes _all_ the income of its citizens and tax residents but allows for credits for income taxes (or deduction of income taxes) paid to foreign countries. Whether this means that you effectively pay _some_ US income tax (capital gains tax) or _no_ US income tax (capital gains tax) on those capital gains depends on the applicable tax rates.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you will. You can use [form 1116](http://www.irs.gov/uac/Form-1116,-Foreign-Tax-Credit) to calculate how much of the tax you paid in Panama can be credited to your US tax.